# How to split with both ", " and "," in one program

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I want to split a string with both ", " and ",". So I have to make a program in which I take input from the user, which is like:- 4, 16, 8, etc. and then double each the number. This is what I have written so far:-

```
def main():
    a = []
    def Convert(string):
        li = list(string.split(", "))
        return li

    def double(lst):
        for i, x in enumerate(lst):
            x = int(x)
            x = x+x
            a.append(x)

    str1 = input()
    n = Convert(str1)
    f = double(n)
    print(a)

     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#Results
inp = 14, -4, 8
out = 28, -8, 16

inp = 14,-4,8
out = error
```

That's why I want to make it so that it will split with ", " and ",". Pls help

Comment: Another option is to split on `","` only, then strip whitespace from each of the parts with `.strip()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this

```
def main():
    a = []
    def Convert(string):
        li = list(string.split("," or ", "))
        return li

    def double(lst):
        for i, x in enumerate(lst):
            x = int(x)
            x = x+x
            a.append(x)

    str1 = input()
    n = Convert(str1)
    f = double(n)
    print(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Simply using **or** for split should work in your case

Comment: The statement `"," or ", "` always return `","` (the first True evaluated value)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that, you can do this:

```
def split_list(val):
    nums=val.split(",")
    return ', '.join(str(int(num.strip())*2) for num in nums)
x=input("Enter numbers: ")
print(split_list(x))
```

Comment: No need to strip int would ignore leading space anyway

Answer (score 1):

To split string using multiple delimeters use re modules split method.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(',|,\s', "14,-4,8")
['14', '-4', '8']
>>> re.split(',|,\s', "14, -4, 8")
['14', ' -4', ' 8']
```

The split method returns list with separated values according to the delimiters you specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace space with null and then split on ',' like follow:-

```
def main():
    a = []
    def Convert(string):
        string = string.replace(" ","")
        li = list(string.split(","))
        return li

    def double(lst):
        for i, x in enumerate(lst):
            x = int(x)
            x = x+x
            a.append(x)

    str1 = input()
    n = Convert(str1)
    f = double(n)
    print(a)

     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```